# How to add a long pause for AVSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: avspeechsynthesizer

I found `--` can add a small pause like the number count down:

```
10--9--8--7--6--5--4--3--2--1--
```

But I don't know how to add a long pause, for like 1 sec?

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Even easier in Swift 3

```
utterance.preUtteranceDelay = 1.0
```

or

```
utterance.postUtteranceDelay = 1.0
```

for a one second delay assuming each number is it's own utterance (like in a loop).  You'd probably have to reduce the delay slightly to take account for the actual speaking duration of each number.

Answer (score 3):

For a normal delay we can add a ":" (colon) between each of the words.

eg:-

```
utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: String(format: "Time: 20 minutes: 15 seconds")
```

the output will ----- " Time (delay) 20 minutes (delay) 15 seconds "

Answer (score 1):

AVSpeechUtterance has postUtteranceDelay properity which decides the delay.
utterance.postUtteranceDelay = 1.0f; // or 1s equaivalent to NSTimeInterval

@property(nonatomic) NSTimeInterval postUtteranceDelay
Description The amount of time a speech synthesizer will wait after the utterance is spoken before handling the next queued utterance.